# How to add custom fields in invoice and wordpress backend?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a wocommerce website, and i want to display a tax that will be custom calculated eg: (weight*0.660+price=tax*quantity) i am using this formula for custom fields calculation. now i want to display the calculated output on user invoice when user checks out. please help me with this

I am using ACF pro plugin to create custom fields and add custom formula.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the template for the invoice and add

```
<?php echo get_field('fieldname', $id); ?>
```

fieldname will be the name of the ACF field and $id will need to be the post id for wherever the field is